# Event doesn't bubble to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling, eventemitter

I have the following project structure:

[image]

`todo-form` fires `created` event and I want to handle this event in `todos` component

**todo-form.component.html:**

```
   <form class="todo-form" (ngSubmit)="create();" #todoForm="ngForm">
       <input name="title" [(ngModel)]="newTodoTitle" type="text" placeholder="Что нужно сделать?" required/>
       <button [disabled]="todoForm.form.invalid" type="submit">Добавить</button>
   </form>
```

method `create` executes(I see it in debugger [image])
**todo-form.component.ts:**

```
 import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";
 ....
 @Component({
     ....
     selector: "todo-form",
     ...
 })
 export class TodoFormComponent {

       @Output() created = new EventEmitter<Todo>();
       ...
       create():void {
            if (this.newTodoTitle) {
                this.created.emit(new Todo(this.newTodoTitle));
            }
        }
        ...
 }
```

**todos.component.html:**

```
<todo-form (created)="onToDoCreated($event)"></todo-form>
...
```

**todos.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "todos",
    templateUrl: "todos.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["todos.component.css"]
})
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    onTodoCreated(todo:ITodo):void {
        this.todoService.addTodo(todo).then(todo=>this.addToCache(todo));
    }
}
```

**main:**

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component"
import {TodoListComponent} from "./components/todos/todo-list/todo-list.component";
import {TodoListItemComponent} from "./components/todos/todo-list-item/todo-list-item.component";
import {TodoFormComponent} from "./components/todos/todo-form/todo-form.component";
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { TodoSeedData } from './components/shared/todo.data';
import { TodosComponent } from "./components/todos/todos.component";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(TodoSeedData)
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, TodoListComponent, TodoListItemComponent, TodoFormComponent, TodosComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

method `onTodoCreated` doesn't invoke.
**Also page refreshes**, athough it is not expected for me.
What did I miss ?

Comment: @echonax What do you mean? import statement in parent ?

Comment: **import {TodoFormComponent} from "./todo-form/todo-form.component";**

Comment: What I meant was are both of the components defined in your `@NgModule`. I couldn't find any mistakes honestly, here's an example use of `@Output`: http://plnkr.co/edit/MeQbC7Jbc8rprMF66aEF?p=preview maybe it'll help

Comment: @echonax I have 2 working examples into sibling components and cannot find difference.

Comment: @echonax file content which contains NgModule added

Comment: @echonax I have found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/41185299/2674303

Comment: Haha, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

After wasting time to investigation I have understand that problem was in typo.

in html:

```
onToDoCreated
```

in ts:

```
onTodoCreated
```

Answer (score 0):

While your typo fixed the problem, your code doesn't use event bubbling. You're still handling the event on the `<todo-form>` component level. For testing bubbling on the parent level try this:

```
<div (created)="onToDoCreated($event)">
   <todo-form></todo-form>
</div>
```

The div won't get the created event. Event bubbling has to be handled using native dom events.